# Fancybox method is not working at all

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fancybox

I'm really confused, I really follow the instruction from [HERE](http://fancybox.net/howto).

The coding is here

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script> !window.jQuery && document.write('<script src="assets/scripts/fancybox/jquery-1.4.3.min.js"><\/script>'); </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/scripts/fancybox/fancybox/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.4.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/scripts/fancybox/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/scripts/fancybox/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css" media="screen" />
```

My html

```
                <p class="gallery-photo"> <a rel="gallery_group" href="photo2.jpg" title=""><img alt="" src="photo2.jpg" /></a> </p>
                <p class="gallery-photo"> <a rel="gallery_group" href="photo3.jpg" title=""><img alt="" src="photo3.jpg" /></a> </p>
                <p class="gallery-photo"> <a rel="gallery_group" href="photo4.jpg" title=""><img alt="" src="photo4.jpg" /></a> </p>
```

Script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("a[rel=gallery_group]").fancybox({
            'transitionIn'      : 'none',
            'transitionOut'     : 'none',
            'titlePosition'     : 'over',
            'titleFormat'       : function(title, currentArray, currentIndex, currentOpts) {
            return '<span id="fancybox-title-over">Image ' + (currentIndex + 1) + ' / ' + currentArray.length + (title.length ? ' &nbsp; ' + title : '') + '</span>';
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

The problem is after I clicked the image, it wont appear like fancybox. I couldn't spot any wrong code. Any ideas?

Comment: The links to those Javscript resources are all relative paths, so are the scripts in those locations? Does your browser console have any errors? What are they?

Comment: Please help us help you and create a http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: I've put all the files inside assets - scripts - fancybox and fancybox again. I've checked with firebug and javascript is not written. I'm really stressed :|

Comment: and can @d_inevitable tell me how to fix this? this is the [link](http://jsfiddle.net/yxXdW/).

Comment: jsfiddle will not host fancebox or mousewheel hosted on their servers. You need to either find them on a cdn, host them somewhere or paste their contents. Also when you find them on CDN you must add them to "External Resources" instead of using script tags. And you need to enable jQuery there too.

Comment: Same applies to your imagages too!

Answer (score 0):

You've almost certainly got a JavaScript error somewhere which is stopping Fancybox from initialising.

To test, reload the page, and then click the image to see if it triggers any errors in your console window.  If you don't have one, get [Firebug](https://getfirebug.com/) and reload the page.

Comment: It is written that no javascript written in this page. I've checked with Firebug. and the location are exact the same. And to be honest, is it possible that `!window.jQuery && document.write('<script src="assets/scripts/fancybox/jquery-1.4.3.min.js"><\/script>');` ? what is this for?